Pull subscription
I set up a transactional publication in SQL Server to be configured as a push subscription, but the distributor error message states 'The process could not connect to the subscriber'. So the subscription is currently set to pull.
I did a test on a different server and it allowed me to create with the same publication a subscription push. Could you advise me on what might be affecting, please?
